# Will the Withdrawal Agreement contain binding commitments to the nature of the Future Relationship?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union

The vote on the European Union Withdrawal Agreement is being used to enable UK Parliamentarians have a say on whether to proceed on the basis of the negotiated deal with the EU.

But will the Withdrawal Agreement Bill 2019 have any binding commitments for the future relationship (currently a seven-page sketch)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The Withdrawal Agreement commits the UK to a number of things, including an indefinite backstop should the future arrangement not resolve the Irish border issue. It also includes commitments to the rights of EU citizens in the UK, and payment of the UK's obligations (the £39 billion) regardless of what is later agreed.

Comment: Thank you. I am also thinking about _commitments_ for a trade deal and frictionless trade, for example.

Comment: @Ben My understanding was that the current version has a commitment to *attempt* to work out a trade deal. The possibility of that failing is the reason for the backstop.